# Chrome Extension with notification like CNN

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am newbie to chrome extension. I have created a simple chrome extension to display latest news updates and it was working fine. Now, whats my doubt is, when i post a new post, the chrome extension icon should show a notification with 1. It means a new post has been updated notification. You can see the CNN news chrome extension.

Is there any possible way to show the notification.

My manifest.json code is,

```
{
    "name": "my name",
    "description": "my desc", 
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "19": "icons/icon19.png"
            },
        "icons": { "16": "icons/icon16.png","48": "icons/icon48.png", "128": "icons/icon128.png" },     
        "default_title": "my name", 
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    }, 
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "update_url": "http://clients2.google.com/service/update2/crx",
    "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' https://www.google.com; object-src 'self'",
    "version": "0.1"
}
```

My Popup.html

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head> 
    <title>my name</title> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body> 

    <div id="feed"></div> 

</body>
</html>
```

My script.js code is

```
   google.load("feeds", "1");

    function initialize() {
      var feed = new google.feeds.Feed("http://feeds.feedburner.com/myname/");
      feed.setNumEntries(10);
      var count = 1;
      feed.load(function(result) {
        if (!result.error) {
          var container = document.getElementById("feed");
          var html = "";
          for (var i = 0; i < result.feed.entries.length; i++) {
            var entry = result.feed.entries[i];
            html = "<div class='feeds'><h5>" + count++ + ". <a href='" + entry.link + "'>" + entry.title + "</a></h5></div>";
            var div = document.createElement("div");
            div.innerHTML = html;
            container.appendChild(div);            
          }
          document.write(html);
        }
      });
    }
    google.setOnLoadCallback(initialize);
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the code you've tried?

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to display a browser action badge (a small number that appears on top of your extension's toolbar icon), you can set/change that by calling `chrome.browserAction.setBadgeText`.